# Convert select query result to XML format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert a result to XML format using a stored procedure my code is as below

```
SELECT 
    K.KeyWord as Result 
FROM 
    SearchKeyword K 
WHERE 
    K.KeyWord LIKE @SearchWord + '%'   
FOR XML PATH 'Root', BINARY BASE64)
```

But that return as below

```
<Root>
   <Result>1</result>
<Root>

<Root>
   <Result>2</result>
<Root>
```

But I need result like below remove one root element

```
<Root>
    <Result>1</Result>
    <Result>2</Result>
    .
    .
    .
</Root>
```

Anyone please help

Comment: based on linked post: `SELECT K.KeyWord AS Result FROM SearchKeyword K FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Root')`

Comment: sorry i have edited my comment it didnt updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select K.KeyWord as Result 
from ... as k
where ...
for xml path(''), root('Root'), binary base64
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7)</kbd>**

Comment: you could have closed this as a duplicate with fewer clicks than it took to answer.... seeing that you have a gold badge.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, @Tanner

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE ([A]NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @tab values ('test')
INSERT INTO @tab values ('test')

SELECT [A] + '' FROM @tab
FOR XML PATH
```

Add a concat to allow for what you want.

Your Code :

```
SELECT K.KeyWord + '' as Result 
FROM SearchKeyword K 
WHERE K.KeyWord LIKE @SearchWord+'%'   
FOR XML PATH 'Root', BINARY BASE64
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Tanner comment works.. thanks for the answer